# Git workflow for customization on remote repository

Tags: git, workflow

I am still not clear in this:

I want to fetch code from opensource project and contribute. But I want to make my private changes also, with possibility to contribute with publicly useful parts of code and make private changes in local repos.

I guess, the way will be:

- clone remote repository
- create a branch for remote version of code "project"
- create local branch "customs", where my customizations will be
- "master" will be my finished customizations

Is then possible to remove some part of original code from my branch "customs", witch will not be automatically synchronized from "project" again, but I still will be able to do contributions for original project? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Clone the repository.
- The master branch should always be exactly the same as the original master branch. (Even though Git can still access the original master branch by using “origin/master” as a branch name if you need one I would still recommand to keep a local branch with it around. It’s a matter of taste, though.)
- Create a branch for your customization; here you can modify everything to your heart’s desire, remove stuff, change stuff, whatever. Your changes here are not touched by what happens in the original repository unless you tell Git to. This branch can be pushed to a public repository if you want — if you don’t want anyone to see it, that’s fine, too.
- Create one or more branches for your public modifications. These branches should be pushed back to the public repository so that the original project can benefit from your modifications if they so choose. If they do, your branches will end up being merged into `master`.
- Now, finally, create a branch for your local build which will contain the original `master` branch, and both of your modified branches. I recommend not getting attached to this branch at all but recreate it every time you modify one of the other branches. This will guarantee that this branch (and your local build) will always contain a clearly defined state. I normally use the following sequence of commands to achieve this:

> ```
> git checkout local
> git reset --hard master
> git merge my-public1 my-public2 my-private1 my-private2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If that opensource project is on GitHub, you need to [fork it](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/) (clone on the server side), and then clone it locally ([forks work also on BitBucket](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Forking+a+bitbucket+Repository), for Mercurial or Git).

From there, you can push to your remote (forked) repo whatever branch you want.
But your [pull requests](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/) will only concern the branch you want to contribute back to the original repo.

If you want your "custom" commits to remain entirely private, make your fork (on GitHub or BitBucket) a private repo.
Note: [private repos are actually free on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/plans)! (and [not free on GitHub](https://github.com/plans)).

The other solutions aren't practical, as they suppose you can push directly to the opensource project (ie be a contributor to that project). This isn't always the case, hence the necessity to fork it first (and make your own remote repo, to which you can contribute as you want), before making pulling requests.

Comment: He's looking to contribute to an open source project NOT necessarily create a new one.

Comment: @thenetimp: he wouldn't create a new one, only isolate its changes in a copy of an existing one.

Comment: yes, but you are telling him to fork the project when he just news to clone the project and work in a branch,

Comment: @thenetimp: see my edit: if he just clone it, he won't be able to push back to it. Hence the fork.

Comment: You're wrong.  That is not how it works.  You clone the repository, and create a branch.  You then ask the maintainers to review your branch for merge with the master directory, so you push YOUR branch for review.  If the maintainers like it they merge the branches,    Forking it starts a totally separate project.

Comment: @thenetimp: I am... at a loss for words. You *cannot* always push your branch. Hence the fork. Please re-read http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/, especially the part which says "The Fork + Pull Model lets anyone fork an existing repository and push changes to their personal fork without requiring access be granted to the source repository. The changes must then be pulled into the source repository by the project maintainer. This model reduces the amount of friction for new contributors". If you aren't still convinced, I guess we will agree to disagree.

Comment: Actually you should re-read that.  It doesn't say forking is necessary, it says some projects prefer it.  In the end he should talk to the project maintainer and find out how HE/SHE wants to manage contributions.

Comment: @thenetimp: my point is: he doesn't have to talk to anyone. He can start a fork and his clone under a minute, and start pushing. Maybe he will eventually be a contributor, but if you want to start *right now* contributing to a project (especially with a mix set of commits, some "private", some public), a fork that you control as you want is the right solution.

Comment: “Forking” and “cloning” are not two different actions; the only difference is that “forking” includes creating a new public repository automatically (at least on GitHub).

Comment: @Bombe: I did mention that forking is a clone on the server. Do you agree with my point which is that, unless the user explicitly mentions he is a contributor, he needs to fork first, then clone that fork in order for him to push whatever he wants, whenever he wants?

Comment: Wau. :-) You are quick. Situation is quite more complicated. Master repository is not at github, nor git repository. I have connected it from svn to my local git repository. I can create public repository, but it will be git, which may be complicated for maintainer of master copy to update from. The main problem I want to ask is: Can I update from remote master and keep my change (include deletions) updated form master copy? My contributions can be done by pathces (I think). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works.

1) Download repository.
2) Create branch do modifications.
3) Share your branch with the open source project maintainers. (there are different ways this is done based on the code repository master location)

If they like your changes, they will merge your branch with master or they will reject them.

If they reject them they will usually tell you why.  Depending on that reason you would either make further changes, fork it to a new project, or abandon your changes.  If the reason for developing is to get involved in an open source project then you never should merge into master, unless than maintainer asks you too.

You should however learn how to rebase a branch so it keeps up with master.